# Can't get the content by golang http.Get(), 500 error instead. Why?

Tags: http, get, go

I can't get a site's content, it returns the 500 error. But if I switch to www.google.com.hk or other sites, it's OK. Why?

The following is the code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://www.eqsn.gov.cn") //the browsers,IE\firefox access it is ok.
    // resp, err := http.Get("http://www.google.com.hk")  //It's ok.

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("http.Get => %v", err.Error())
    }
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Printf("\n%v\n\n", string(body))
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like it has anything to do with `Go`. You're acknowledging that you're getting a response, so `Go` is working properly. I might be convinced that it was a `Go` problem if you were actually setting the same request headers that a browser would set.

Comment: The site you requested is getting something wrong, `curl http://www.eqsn.gov.cn/` returns 500, too.

Comment: this is interesting. Said URL loads fine in my browser. It might be possible, that it analyzes the user-agent.

Answer (score 4):

If an execution of `http.Get()` returns an error 500 (internal server error), it is pretty likely that this error comes from the server. In fact, let's try manually. The option `-D-` dumps the headers.

```
$ curl -D- http://www.eqsn.gov.cnHTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 02:01:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 538
X-Powered-By: 
X-AspNet-Version: 
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 
Server: 
X-Cache: MISS from CNC-JSWX-254-131.fastcdn.com
X-Cache: MISS from CT-ZJNB-152-196.fastcdn.com
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator,
 [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred,
and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>
```

As you can see, the server gives you an error 500. Go works completely fine; it gives you the error 500 the server sends. If you have further questions, feel free to ask.